# Why powershell does not save file

Tags: windows, powershell

I execute command like:

```
 pg_restore.exe --jobs "8" --format=d -C -d test -U postgres -h localhost 'C:\backup\s\db\mydatabase.sqlc' > E:\output.txt
```

But Powershell only logs to console and does not save anything to file.

If I execute:

```
'test' > E:\output.txt
```

Then the file has string `test` inside.

Comment: Does the command gets executed as expected and just does not write any output into your file? (btw. that's not really PowerShell)

Comment: I'm just guessing that it's a problem due to stderr and stdout. Try `pg_restore.exe --jobs "8" --format=d -C -d test -U postgres -h localhost 'C:\backup\s\db\mydatabase.sqlc' > E:\output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: ok - `pg_restore.exe --jobs "8" --format=d -C -d est -U postgres -h localhost 'C:\backup\s\db\mydatabase.sqlc' 2>&1 >  E:\output.txt`

works

Answer (score 0):

Try using like 'test' | out-file E:\output.txt

Comment: It was not about 'test' cause it worked. It was about the first statement.